# is JsonP working with Opera, Chrome & Safari?

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, cross-domain, jsonp

On a  web site that I am building , 
when you log in (because the database is on an other server),
I use **json padding** to check if the user as the right credentials.

It's working *flawlessly* (ie7,ie8 & FF), until I tried it on **chrome, safari & opera** where it's a complete disaster.

```
    $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  url: "http://someurl.com",
  data: aRequestData,
  cache: false,
  error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // typically only one of textStatus or errorThrown
    // will have info
    alert("Error occured textStatus=" + textStatus + " errorThrown=" + errorThrown);
  },
  success: function(data) {
    alert('success');    
  }
});
```

Plain and simple and it works in browser window, however, to my big surprise it did not work in chrome, safari & opera, never got to the success alert.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a perfectly good question.  +1'ing to counter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was left over html page header, in a "Thickbox" (jQuery Thickbox plugin) where the ajax call was made!

Firefox or IE don't mind repeated headers in that case, but the WebKit engine does!

I just had to remove the extra headers, and everything was back on tracks.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the built in developer tools for Safari and Chrome to check if you get a response with HTTP status code 200 from your request?

In Chrome you can access these tools from the 'View' menu, choose the 'Resources' tab to see all requests made. I think you'll need to activate these tools in some setting when using Safari.
[image]

You could also try to create version without jQuery to rule out errors made there, if you don't get status 200 from your calls I think jQuery will fail without calling any error functions, the documentation for using JSONP with jQuery is not very concise regarding error handling.

Create a html file with an edited version of the following content and load it in your browsers:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <title />
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function ws_results(obj) {
             alert(obj);
         }
      </script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://someurl.com?foo=bar&amp;callback=ws_results" />
   </head>
   <body />
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, I have actually found a solution to that one and forgot to write down the answer.